# Arrange and dock windows in web application

Tags: javascript, html, windows

We would like to port a desktop app to a Web application.
Here we use the concept of an Single-page application to keep as much smooth interaction as possible.

Could anybody suggest a JavaScript UI framework, which enables to arrange and dock windows (parts of the page) similiar to the feature in Visual Studio and other IDEs.
Of course it does not have to be such sophisticated.

There are many frameworks, which easily enables "drag and drop" and other parts you need for this, but we would like to extend rather than write from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using [extjs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/example/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/) as a basis for your application, it has lots of components for a single page app.

Also, you can use [jqueryui](http://jqueryui.com/demos/) with [this plugin](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/complex.html), and integrate it into any other framework.

Answer (score 0):

I've searched the web. 
The powerful JavaScript frameworks ExtJS in version 5 does support this feature.
http://dev.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/examples/portal/index.html
Older versions does not support it. Because of that I don't found it immediately.

The competitor Kendo UI also supports the basic functionality. http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/sortable/sortable-panels
Can't say wether it still works if you make it resizable.

This frameworks are pretty heavy, so maybe it's possible to use small libraries.
I've found two promising JavaScript libraries.
The jquery plugin gridster.js, which supports "drag and drop" a container and auto arrange the layout, besides it supports resize a container.

Even better seems to be the library Packery.
It has a binding to jquery ui, so you can extend it with its functionality. e.g. handle attribute.